# How to force vdso memory to be in fixed address?

Tags: linux, memory, vdso

It appears that there is no information in the executable about where vdso should be. Assuming that I can control how the program is compiled, linked and written, how can I force it to be at the address I want it to be?[image]

Comment: You probably can't, and I don't see why you want that. How are you compiling & linking your binary? Do you know about [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: I know about ASLR, and I know vdso address is randomized. But I really need to have that memory. I can give it some space somewhere else.

Comment: Then you might need to patch your kernel. Good luck!

Comment: Ehhh i hoped it won't come to this...

Comment: Did you read [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) ?